# How to add a token to my api using mvc 4?

Tags: c#, api, access-token

How might I add a secure token to access the api so that not everyone can get it. I would like the format of my url to be : `api.example.com/*key*/person?id=5` and when I send this request it will return if the key is valid if not valid it will return invalid login. I am using mvc 4 api and C# to make this and a link or something will be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key phrase you are looking for most like is that you need to create and add a custom `ActionFilterAttribute`.

A quick search on google turned up this blog article which talks about doing this [exact thing](http://codebetter.com/johnvpetersen/2012/04/02/making-your-asp-net-web-apis-secure/) (along with some other filters).

Just in case there's some link rot here's the gist (excerpts from the blog article):

1. Come up with some scheme for generating/verifying the API tokens
2. Create you attribute that uses the verification from step 1 in an attribute
3. Add the attribute to the global configuration

**CODE**

```
public class TokenValidationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
  public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
  {
   string token;

   try
   {
    token = actionContext.Request.Headers.GetValues("Authorization-Token").First();
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
    {
     Content = new StringContent("Missing Authorization-Token")
    };
    return;
   }

   try
   {
    //This part is where you verify the incoming token
    AuthorizedUserRepository.GetUsers().First(x => x.Name == RSAClass.Decrypt(token));
    base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
   }
   catch (Exception)
   {
    actionContext.Response = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
    {
     Content = new StringContent("Unauthorized User")
    };
    return;
   }
    }
  }
}
```

To make these action filters global, the following code in the Global.asax Application_Start() will do the trick:

```
var config = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration;
config.Filters.Add(new TokenValidationAttribute());
```

Comment: This what I think I looking for just need to work out some bugs but thanks

Comment: Just ran into one bump in the road which is that the new mvc 4 doesnt support FormatterContext anymore :( hope I can get it to work without it :D

Comment: After some minor changes it works and also for anyone looking to do this it works great and the website works great

Answer (score 0):

At my work, we create a hash of the username and password and use that for the user token. You could just generate a GUID for them, keeping track of the time it was created and who it belongs to.

Comment: Well this is going to be private api where only 4 or 5 of the people will have access to it out of all the users in the database so I need to find a way to check the token and also integrate into mvc 4